# Access static files from src/main/resources in Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In my SpringBoot project I would like to read an image file located in:

[image]

I tried:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("android.png");
File f = new File(url.getPath());
```

and:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("static/images/android.png");
File f = new File(url.getPath());
```

but the result is null.

EDIT: this worked

```
try {
   File file = new ClassPathResource("static/images/android.png").getFile();    
} catch (IOException e) {

}
```

Comment: Try a leading slash /static/images/android.png"

Comment: try `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("static/images/android.png")`

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Spring, then it's better to use the built-in [ClassPathResource](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html) class to access files within your classpath.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
File file = new ClassPathResource("/images/android.png").getFile();
```

because we can access static folder from anywhere

Answer (score 1):

you can use `this.getClass().getResource("/static/images").getFile();` to get the folder location and then append with the file name to get the file location.

Example

```
String path=this.getClass().getResource("/static/images").getFile();
File File f = new File(path+"/​android.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("/static/images/android.png");
```